# Entity Framework .NET Core returns 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.' but not in Debugger

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

**The problem:**

on C#, MVC API with Angular 6 front end on IIS deployed solution.

A simple HTML table with 8 filtering fields on specific columns runs queries on the back-end through an API HttpGet call. The function itself works ok, but **NOT** for specific strings. On the field 'Description' for example, the back-end returns 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values' when below strings are used. Values are correctly passed between front and back-end and the API call mostly returns the appropriate data.

However strings such as `app` and longer than `app` such as `application`, `cert` and longer such as `certificate` will return the 'Data is Null' error.

If I use `f` as the input for `transmittal` I get the 'Data is Null' error.
If however I use `crc` on `document` and **THEN** use `f` as the input for `transmittal` the function returns normal data??

This only happens in the deployed state, the problem does not occur when debugging the code. When debugging, the code returns the expected results and always produces the correct response.

the service call using a set of 'chained' where statements to build an IQueryable which gets called to return a `.ToListAsync()` at the end of the sequence.

---

**Using:**

- IIS, version 10, running on Virtual Machine
- Operating System IIS virtual machine: Windows Server 2016
- .Net Core: 2.1
- EntityFrameworkCore: 2.1.11
- SQL Server 2012 (running on same VM)
- VS 2019
- SQL Server Management Studio 2018

---

**the Controller code**

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string TR, string DA, string DO, string RE, string TY, string DD, string DI, string OR, string DE)
        {
        return Ok(await _archiveService.Search(TR, DA, DO, RE, TY, DD, DI, OR, DE));
        }
```

---

**the ArchiveService code**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Search(
            string transmittal,
            string date,
            string document, 
            string revision,
            string type,
            string description, 
            string discipline, 
            string origin, 
            string destination)
        {
                var result = _db.TblCorrespondenceLog.AsQueryable();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(transmittal))
                    result = result.Where(f => f.TransmittalNo.Contains(transmittal));

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
                {

                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(document))
                    result = result.Where(f => f.CompanyDocumentNo.ToLower().Contains(document));

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
                    result = result.Where(f => f.DocumentType.ToLower() == type);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
                    result = result.Where(f => f.DocumentDescription.ToLower().Contains(description));

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(discipline))
                    result = result.Where(f => f.Discipline.ToLower() == discipline);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(origin))
                    result = result.Where(f => f.OriginatorCode.ToLower() == origin);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination))
                    result = result.Where(f => f.SupplierCode.ToLower() == destination);    

                return await result.ToListAsync();
}
```

The fields that give the errors are the fields that have the `.Contains()` clause

When I use SQL writer to obtain the query that get's fired to the server I get the below query, which results in the 'Data is Null' error when the `.ToListAsync()` gets called:

```
SELECT [f].[uID], [f].[Action_Required], [f].[Approved_Responded], [f].[Area_Code], [f].[Company_Document_No], 
[f].[Discipline], [f].[Document_Description], [f].[Document_Type], [f].[fileUID], [f].[Link], [f].[Originator_Code], 
[f].[Reference_Document], [f].[ResponsibelEngineer], [f].[ResubDate], [f].[ResubTransmittal], [f].[Rev], 
[f].[Sequential_Number], [f].[Sheet_Number], [f].[Supplier_Code], [f].[TDate], [f].[Transmittal_Date], [f].[Transmittal_No], 
[f].[Transmittal_Type], [f].[TRN_Originator], [f].[TurnAroundDate], [f].[Unit_Code], 
[f].[TransmitUID] 
FROM [tblCorrespondenceLog] AS [f] 
WHERE CHARINDEX(N'f', [f].[Transmittal_No]) > 0
```

Which, when fired from SMSS (SQL Server Management Studio 2018) works perfectly fine?

If I use `crc` as input for `document` I get data returned as normal but the query is only marginally different:

```
SELECT [f].[uID], [f].[Action_Required], [f].[Approved_Responded], [f].[Area_Code], [f].[Company_Document_No], 
[f].[Discipline], [f].[Document_Description], [f].[Document_Type], [f].[fileUID], [f].[Link], [f].[Originator_Code], 
[f].[Reference_Document], [f].[ResponsibelEngineer], [f].[ResubDate], [f].[ResubTransmittal], [f].[Rev], 
[f].[Sequential_Number], [f].[Sheet_Number], [f].[Supplier_Code], [f].[TDate], [f].[Transmittal_Date], [f].[Transmittal_No], 
[f].[Transmittal_Type], [f].[TRN_Originator], [f].[TurnAroundDate], [f].[Unit_Code], 
[f].[TransmitUID] 
FROM [tblCorrespondenceLog] AS [f]
WHERE (CHARINDEX(N'f', [f].[Transmittal_No]) > 0) AND (CHARINDEX(N'crc', LOWER([f].[Company_Document_No])) > 0)
```

So...
Why does entity framework give me a 'Data is Null' error only on specific strings and in specific combinations. Where the function would otherwise return proper values even if filtering on the 'problem' fields (using different strings of course)?

Comment: You generally don’t want to call `.ToLower()` within your queries since that will never run on the database server, making this very inefficient.

Comment: @poke I had added that in an attempt to resolve the issue. Prior to that (i.e. without the ToLower()) the query responded the same? And, as indicated, for some queriy strings the method works fine -if inefficient perhaps-. It is for very specific strings that it fails?

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Profiler to ensure that sql query is executing against your database? Also, for the deployed website ensure that the database user has select permissions on the tblCorrespondenceLog table.

Comment: please make sure that the data which is return by the query is not null. and you are using the same database with iis?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes, I've tried running the queries on SMSS on the same production database. The SQL that get's generated by EntityFramework produces correct results when called directly on the DB. But that same data gives an error when translated into a list on the .ToListAsync() call. Username etc. all identical so that is not the problem as the query -as indicated- mostly returns correct results

Comment: @JalpaPanchal The data that is returned from the queries is not null, as stated. If I run the queries directly on the same database I get results, so the returned result are not null. To give one example that could not be null; If I start typing 'a' I get results, if I increase to 'ap' I get null, if I continue typing until I reach 'application t' I get results, implying I should get results for all intermediate steps between 'a' and 'application t' ?

Comment: @mtholen I am assuming you are connecting to production database using the same user your application uses while executing the queries using SSMS

Comment: @MohsinMehmood The connection is not the culprit. The same connection returns correct data from the production DB if another search text is used. So the only difference is the search text? As indicated in my answer to JalpaPancha above. The behaviour seems to be erratic? If I start typing 'a' I get correct results, if I increase to 'ap' I get the 'Data is null' error, if I continue typing until I reach 'application t' I get correct results again, implying I should get results for all intermediate steps between 'a' and 'application t' as there are apparently records for the latter entry ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by a disconnect between the .NET Core Entity Class and the database table;

The class Configiration was set as:

```
     builder.Property(e => e.DocumentDescription)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("Document_Description")
            .HasMaxLength(150);
```

but the database table had this field as `allow null` therefore sometimes returning `null` where entity framework did not expect to see a `null`.

removing the `.IsRequired()` bit did the job.

```
     builder.Property(e => e.DocumentDescription)
            //.IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("Document_Description")
            .HasMaxLength(150);
```

Funny enough though, this didn't produce errors in the development environment but DID cause problems when deployed. I haven't been able to figure out why there is a difference, but at least it works now!